# How to call Intent Api from postman or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, einstein-analytics, einstein, node.js, react

```
 curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" -H "Cache-Control: no- 
    cache" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "data=@C:\Data\weather.csv" -F "type=text-intent"
```

https://api.einstein.ai/v2/language/datasets/upload
[image]

[image]

```
 const headers = {
     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
     'Authorization': 'Bearer IJHEGMZTI5BDGTZSIVBU2MSEJRFE4RBTKM3TEQSDINKEYNRTK43VKMSEJ4ZTIQKNKZIU6UKWIRFVEURSIVNEKWBWLFEESQJSLJAUST22IRJUSN2OLBMEQRCCLI2VSQS2K43ECSKTLIZTKNSHJNBUKMSYIFHDOTKUKFFFC7COIE',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
  var dataset = {
     data: "@C:\\Users\\harshit.t\\Downloads\\weather.csv",
     type: "text-intent"
  };
  axios.post("https://api.einstein.ai/v2/language/datasets/upload", dataset, {
     headers: headers
  })
     .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
     })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
     })
```

}

Comment: welcome to SFSE, Please add more details like where to struck and what error you got.

Comment: In addition to sdandamud1's notes (see [ask]), please tag your question appropriately. This post has nothing to do with `lightning-aura-components`, `community`, or `salesforcedx`.

Comment: While i am calling api https://api.einstein.ai/v2/language/datasets/upload  am getting 404 bad request error